# How to store multiline outputs from 'hub' command in a variable?

Tags: bash, github, hub

If I use the `hub` command to create a pull request on GitHub and I get an error then it is outputted on four lines:

```
hub pull-request -p -b MyOrg:main -h Test_Branch -m "testing"
```

output:

```
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'Test_Branch' set up to track remote branch 'Test_Branch' from 'MyOrg'.
Error creating pull request: Unprocessable Entity (HTTP 422)
A pull request already exists for MyOrg:Test_Branch.
```

Now if I try to store the output this way:

`output=$(hub pull-request -p -b MyOrg:main -h Test_Branch -m "testing")`

then oddly enough only the second line is stored in `output`.

If I print it I see only the second line:

`echo $output`

result:

`Branch 'Test_Branch' set up to track remote branch 'Test_Branch' from 'MyOrg'.`

My overall goal is to capture the output and not have it printed to the user. I just want to show them a simple error message (instead of four lines of output). Ideally, I just want to do `grep` on `Error creating pull request` and based on that print a dedicated error message.

Can anybody tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I would guess that the other lines go to STDERR? To keep both STDOUT and STDERR, try adding `2>&1` at the end: `output=$(hub ..."testing" 2>&1)`

Comment: @mivk that solved the issue! Thanks a lot! If you write it as an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other lines are probably printed to STDERR. When using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), only STDOUT is captured into the vraiable.

To get both, you need to redirect STDERR to STDOUT by appending `2>&1` to your command:

```sh
output=$( your_command 2>&1 )
```